# How to know where is the error from react native remote debugging?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi i'm new to react and react native and i have some console errors but i can't find it in the code to fix it, i have only the `"blob:http://localhost:8081/81599964-c0ed-4427-8b93-7b5cc356a8dd:15195"` url and this go no where in my code, please any help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your codes on here? If you remove "fontSize" and "fontWeight" line it will be fixed and it's not an exception, just warning